# Test For Legal Assignments

Tags: c++

I've been asked to find which of the following assignments are legal. It gives me a function as shown below. When I type it in it gives me errors for some and others don't receive any errors so i'm assuming that those are the legal ones. But I want to test it but i would like to know how to implement the method into main.

```
void f(int p[])
{
// Which of the following assignments are legal in C++?
int *q ;
const int* r;
int s[10];
//p =q;    not legal 
//p = r;   not legal 
p = s;  //legal
q  = p; //legal
q = s;  //legal
r = p;  //legal
r = s;  //legal
//s = p;   not legal
//s = q;   not legal
//s = r;   not legal
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You want to test whether a statement in C++ is allowed or not?

Comment: `p=q` must be legal.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main() {
    int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    f(arr);

return 0;
}
```